# how to make swagger post parameter have a default request example

Tags: java

Is it possbile to give a default request example in swagger page? Now on the server side, it define like this:

```
 Response<PageBeanExt<ReportUserAppDateStatisticResponse, ReportUserAppDateStatisticResponse>> statisticByGameAndDate(@RequestBody ReportUserRequest request);
```

now I want the swagger ui have a default request example so that I can simple send a request without composite request json every time:

[image]

what should I do to make it? I have already tried this but it seems not work:

```
 static final String appStatistic = "{\n" +
            "  \"roomType\":\"1\",\n" +
            "  \"startDate\":\"2021-2-15 0:0:0 000\",\n" +
            "  \"endDate\":\"2021-12-25 23:59:59 999\"\n" +
            "}\n";

    /**
     * @return
     */
    @PostMapping("/detail/app-date-statistic/")
    Response<PageBeanExt<ReportUserAppDateStatisticResponse, ReportUserAppDateStatisticResponse>> statisticByGameAndDate(@ApiParam(defaultValue = appStatistic) @RequestBody ReportUserRequest request);
```

Comment: Which dependency you have used? `SpringFox` or `SpringDoc`?

Comment: I am using SpringFox @SSK

Comment: You can use `@ApiModelProperty(example = "1111")`, in example add you desired values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate your request object, ReportUserRequest with swagger annotations and specify examples in those annotations for additional spec details. In your case check the @ApiModelProperty which can be set for a specific property

For e.g:

```
@ApiModel(value="Your report user request description")
public class ReportUserRequest{
@ApiModelProperty(value="A description for the key", example="example value", required= true)
private String key;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@ApiModelProperty(example = "1111")`

```
public class User{

   @ApiModelProperty(example = "1111")
    private String userName;
    
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "Testing")
    private String role;
}
```

It shows on swagger as

[image: Swagge image]

Comment: is it possible to get these values form database ?

Comment: @David I have not tried this, but there is option to give the reference values